# Azure API App (Nodejs) returns Internal Server Error rather than specific error message

Tags: node.js, azure, web-config, azure-api-apps

I have deployed my nodejs api on Azure.  When there is an error I continue to receive Internal Server Error (500).  But I want it to return my error message that I specify.

Locally it does what I intend.  On Azure it only returns Internal Server Error.

**Local response:**

[image: Local response:]

**Azure response:**

[image: Azure response:]

My webconfig is being genreated automatically by azure deployment.  But here is what is in there.

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

How do I get the response from Azure to return the same thing that I am getting locally?

**Dependencies:**

[image]

Here is one of my endpoints:

```
'use strict';
var dataProvider = require('../data/dp.js');

module.exports = {

    post: function myEndpoint(req, res, next) {

        var status = 200;
        var provider = dataProvider['post']['200'];
        provider(req, res, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
                return;
            }
            res.status(status).send(data && data.responses);
        });
    }
};
```

If the err gets hit then it returns the responsive above, respectively.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your "dependencies" in the package.json and demo code?  I can't repro the issue in my side.

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT - added information requested.